# How to disable system volume reduce in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio

I have a flash chat application and when app create new conversation system reduce volume of incoming sound stream at 80%(and any other sounds). How can i disable volume reduce from flash?

---

Here is some additional information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468869/problem-with-sound-quality

---

i think only win7 has that problem because of http://streaminggates.com/content/adjust-volume-level-when-place-or-receive-telephone-calls-in-windows-7

Comment: You'd better rewrite your question. Both links you provide for more information seem to be completely unrelated to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think if that were possible it would have been exploited by the more obnoxious side of the advertising community by now.

Comment: Why? I just want to have 100% of system level sound volume. For example we have system sound volume = 36%. With sound reduce i have only 36/5=7%! 7% instead of 36%.